# Understanding multiple threads and EventWaitHandle

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, blocking

I am trying to understand this code segment here I found online:

```
private EventWaitHandle wh = new AutoResetEvent();

private void WorkerThread() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        wh.WaitOne();
        //Do work.
    }
}

public void StartWorking()
{
    wh.Set();
}
```

So I understand that the thread once it hits WaitOne() it will block until Set() is called, but what if multiple threads reach the .WaitOne()? Will they all be blocked or just one? If Set() is called will it release all the threads or just one?

Edit- I am reading more and trying it and a follow up question: If ManualResetEvent is what accomplishes what I described above how does it behave when there are multiple threads waiting at once? Would a AutoResetEvent release them one at a time with just one Set() call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AutoResetEvent`: after one `Set()` called, only one thread will pass `WaitOne()`; other threads still waiting the second `Set()`.

`ManualResetEvent`: after one `Set()` called, thread will pass `WaitOne()` forever, unless you manually call `Reset()`.

Comment: Thanks for a short and easy to understand comment! Was just wrestling with ManualResetEvent and having multiple threads consume it at once when I saw this. Problem solved! Many thanks :)